# SQL optimization GROUP BY same table, same column

Tags: sql, oracle, query-optimization

I have this `GROUP BY` query where I need to select some records from `TABLE_1` and aggregate them.

The `SELECTs` are similar but I need to aggregate `LON` and `BHAM` separately as they are two different concepts but reside in same table.

My question is can I write the below differently in oracle that will optimize the performance of the query?

```
SELECT  *
FROM (
        (    SELECT  /*+ full(t1) */ 
                t3.custId AS ID,       
                t2.secID AS SEC_ID, 
                t1.org_date AS SETT_DATE,
                SUM(t1.amount) AS TOTAL
            FROM test.TABLE_1 t1 
            INNER JOIN test.TABLE_2 t2 on t2.a_code = t1.a_code  and t2.c_code = t1.c_code and t2.expiry_date > trunc(sysdate)
            INNER JOIN test.TABLE_3 t3 on t3.account_id = t1.account_id 
            WHERE t1.city = 'LON'         
                AND t1.amount < 50000 and t1.amount > -50000
            GROUP BY t3.custId,  t2.secID, t1.org_date

        )

          UNION ALL

        (    SELECT  /*+ full(t1) */ 
                t3.custId AS ID,      
                t2.secID AS SEC_ID,
                t1.org_date AS SETT_DATE,
                SUM(t1.amount) AS TOTAL
            FROM test.TABLE_1 t1 
            INNER JOIN test.TABLE_2 t2 on t2.a_code = t1.a_code  and t2.c_code = t1.c_code and t2.expiry_date > trunc(sysdate)
            INNER JOIN test.TABLE_3 t3 on t3.account_id = t1.account_id 
            WHERE t1.city = 'BHAM'
                AND t3.alias = 'ABC' 
                AND t1.amount < 50000 and t1.amount > -50000
            GROUP BY t3.custId,  t2.secID, t1.org_date
        )   
    )
 ORDER BY ID,  SEC_ID, 
          CASE WHEN SETT_DATE < TRUNC(sysdate) THEN trunc(sysdate) ELSE TRUNC(SETT_DATE) end
```

Comment: Do you need them in separate rows, or are separate columns acceptable?

Comment: @Boneist separate columns are not accepted as my processes is using columns ID, SEC_ID, SETT_DATE returned by query and mapped to destination. I need them in separate rows as Im processing each row

Comment: Ok. BTW, your query would fail, since your `t1.org_date as sett_date` in the selected column list doesn't match the `case when t1.org_date < ....` in the group by. Was that a typo in your question?

Comment: Also, how do you know which row belongs to which city?

Comment: @Boneist correct, case was initially there on select I missed it typing in SO. to keep query short for now, I keep them consistent in select + group by

Comment: @Boneist re:which row belongs to which city. my process doesn't care about city, but when selecting, some particular `custId` are not in `LON` and only in `BHAM ` and I need those brought in too with `LON` ones

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `union all` and everything after, remove outer `select`, write `where` clause like here:

```
where -50000 < t1.amount and t1.amount < 50000 
  and (t1.city = 'LON' or (t1.city = 'BHAM' and t3.alias = 'ABC'))
```

Comment: I don't think that's what the OP wants - that would produce a single row, rather than two rows for the different city/alias combinations.

Comment: @Boneist - outer select groups rows only using id and sec_id.

Comment: The outer query doesn't do a group by or distinct. The OP is wanting rows for different city/alias combinations, which would get squashed into a single row with your suggestion, since city and alias aren't part of the group by.

Comment: You are right. So it's enough to add city to `group by`.

Comment: Ok, so from what the OP has commented on my answer, seems like your answer is actually the right one! D'oh!

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the city column into the group by, and update the where clause to get both sets of rows, e.g.:

```
SELECT custid,
       sec_id,
       sett_date,
       total
FROM   (SELECT t3.custid AS id,
               t2.secid AS sec_id,
               CASE
                 WHEN t1.org_date < trunc(SYSDATE) THEN
                  trunc(SYSDATE)
                 ELSE
                  trunc(t1.org_date)
               END AS sett_date,
               t1.city,
               SUM(t1.amount) AS total
        FROM   test.table_1 t1
        INNER  JOIN test.table_2 t2
        ON     t2.a_code = t1.a_code
        AND    t2.c_code = t1.c_code
        AND    t2.expiry_date > trunc(SYSDATE)
        INNER  JOIN test.table_3 t3
        ON     t3.account_id = t1.account_id
        WHERE  (t1.city = 'LON' OR (t1.city = 'BHAM' AND t3.alias = 'ABC'))
        AND    t1.amount < 50000
        AND    t1.amount > -50000
        GROUP  BY t3.custid,
                  t2.secid,
                  CASE
                    WHEN t1.org_date < trunc(SYSDATE) THEN
                     trunc(SYSDATE)
                    ELSE
                     trunc(t1.org_date)
                  END)
ORDER  BY id,
          sec_id,
          sett_date;
```

However, I'm surprised you need both rows, since you can't tell which belongs to which city. I suspect you need to include the city (and maybe alias) columns into the final results.

Comment: the `custId` setup against `BHAM` would not be found in `LON`

Comment: Ok, if a single custid can only ever be in one city then you wouldn't need to include them in the group by - as per Ponder's answer!

Comment: Hmm, if you excluded the city from the group by, then Ponder's answer is the correct answer.